# Probability Theory: Generating Functions of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, generating-functions, geometric-probability

Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables with the geometric distribution with parameter
$p > 0$.

> (a) Compute the mean of $Z = XY$.

I got that $E(Z) = 1/p^2$

> (b) Compute the probability generating function of $W = X + 2Y$

This is my work so far: [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J0m8.jpg)

I'm not sure if this right and if it is the final answer or not. Please help.

---

Comment: Hi! Please typeset your mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Doing so will help keep your answer from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, experienced users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. ¶ For example, `$\sum_{i=0}^\infty s^i P_w(i) = \mathbb{E}(s^w)$` yields $\sum_{i=0}^\infty s^i P_w(i) = \mathbb{E}(s^w)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we have
$$
\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y] = \frac1p\cdot\frac1p=\frac1{p^2}.
$$
Recall that the probability generating function of $X$ is
$$
G_X(s) := \mathbb E[s^X] = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }  (1-p)^{k-1}p s^k= \frac{ps}{1-(1-p)s},
$$
so the probability generating function of $2Y$ is
$$
G_{2Y}(s) := \mathbb E[s^{2Y}] = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }  (1-p)^{k-1}p s^{2k}= \frac{p s^2}{1-(1-p) s^2}.
$$
By independence, the probability generating function of $W$ is the product of the probability generating functions of $X$ and $2Y$:
\begin{align}
G_W(s) &= G_X(s)G_{2Y}(s)\\
&= \frac{ps}{1-(1-p)s}\cdot\frac{p s^2}{1-(1-p) s^2}\\
&= \frac{p^2s^3}{(1-(1-p)s)(1-(1-p)s^2)}.
\end{align}